# How Gremlin query same sql like for search feature

Tags: sql, gremlin, orientdb

Im using OrientDB type graph. I need syntax of Gremlin for search same SQL LIKE operator

```
LIKE 'search%' or LIKE '%search%'
```

I've check with has and filter (in http://gremlindocs.com/). However it's must determine exact value is passed with type property. I think this is incorrect with logic of search.

Thanks for anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
g.V().filter({ it.getProperty("foo").startsWith("search") })
```

or

```
g.V().filter({ it.getProperty("foo").contains("search") })
```

Comment: and `.matches(".*search.*")`

Comment: is there any way to do 'not like' ?

Comment: Just return the inverted result. `g.V().filter({ !it.getProperty("foo").contains("search") })`

Comment: What Gremlin server are you using for this? Titan? Janus?

Comment: First, this answer is 5 years old, Janus didn't exist at this time. Next, I don't think I used any server to test this query.

Answer (score 12):

For Cosmos Db Gremlin support

```
g.V().has('foo', TextP.containing('search'))
```

You can find the documentation [Microsoft Gremlin Support docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support) And [TinkerPop Reference](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/reference/#a-note-on-predicates)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `filter` with a bit of regex:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V.filter{it.name.matches(".*ark.*")}.name
==>marko
```

or with more Groovy syntactic sugar:

```
gremlin> g.V.filter{it.name==~/.*ark.*/}.name 
==>marko
```

The above answer (and the accepted answer) apply to TinkerPop 2.x and **the following applies to 3.x** which is the version currently in wide usage:

At this time TinkerPop 3.x does not support regex as part of the Gremlin core language, however regex may be available to the specific graph system you are using (DSE Graph, JanusGraph, etc) and those graphs will supply their own libraries to extend Gremlin with a regex predicate (and/or other search options like fuzzy and tokenizations). Consult the documentation of your graph for what is available.

A graph specific extension will be the most efficient way to do a regex based search as it will rely on internal indexing functions that are optimized to handle such things, but there are methods to do in-memory sorts of regex searches through closures which are similar to the TinkerPop 2.x answer above.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().filter{it.get().value('name').matches(".*ark.*")}
==>v[1]
```

Since we're using a closure, we can place whatever Java (in this case Groovy) code we want in that function. Note that for `it.get().value('name')` the `it` is a Groovy notation that gets refers to the current `Traverser` in the stream of `V()` and it holds a `Vertex` object which is retrieved via `get()`.

This approach will work wherever closures are accepted, but they don't work everywhere as not all graphs will support them. If you are not on the JVM (e.g. python) then you are likely submitting Gremlin scripts to a server or using bytecode based requests. If you are submitting scripts then you should be able to submit the request just as shown above. If you are using bytecode then you have to   explicitly declare the lambda as a string in your traversal as shown [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_the_lambda_solution_2) for Python.

Ultimately, use of closures/lambdas are not recommended as they reduce portability of your code, expose security holes, etc. If you need regex, it would be best to utilize a graph that has native support for them and a code library that contains the custom predicates specific to your programming language.

Comment: How can I use regex (matches) with gremlin javascript, please?

Comment: @CongBangDO - Did you ever find out how?

Comment: i've updated this answer for TinkerPop 3.x - note that gremlin-javascript doesn't yet support closure/lambdas for bytecode based traversals. you would have to send a script. not a great solution, but it's all that there is.

Comment: Many thanks for the update @stephenmallette - I'm very new to all of this.  May I ask what's "not great" about sending scripts?

Comment: TinkerPop is typically recommending bytecode as the preferred way to do things. Recall how ugly it is to embed SQL strings in your code - not so different for Gremlin. you get no IDE support like autocomplete, aren't made aware of compile time errors, etc. Scripts are also a security hole if not properly configured, as they can enable arbitrary code execution. Scripts also bind you to writing Gremlin in a language other than the one you might be using - if you code JS then you have to write Gremlin as Groovy if you submit scripts.

Comment: Makes sense; and yes, it is a bit of a step back to the dark ages having DB strings in code.  I'll just have to try and use it only when absolutely necessary.  Last question (for now :)) -  I see you contribute actively contribute to the tinkerpop code (thanks) - are closures/lambdas part of the road map for the gremlin-javascript?

Comment: yes - it's just something to do that hasn't been done yet (support among graph providers however may be spotty - not all support lambdas for the same reason as scripts): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2001

Comment: @LG Unfortunately, I didn’t.

Answer (score 4):

For people finding this answer here is an updated version of how you can search (very similar to the accepted answer)

For the gremlin console (gremlin.sh):

```
g.V().filter({ it.get().value("foo").contains("search") })
```

Also if you have your index backend being ElasticSearch (might work for other indexing backends as well) this works as well:

```
g.V().has("foo", Text.textContains("search"))
```

Answer (score 4):

For JanusGraph with Gremlin Python (gremlin_python):

```
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import TextP
g.V().has('foo', TextP.containing('search'))
```

Source: https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-backend/text-search/

Answer (score 3):

As one of the committers of the SimpleGraph project i know of the solution implemented in that project

https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplegraph/blob/master/simplegraph-core/src/main/java/com/bitplan/gremlin/RegexPredicate.java

**Example**

```
g().V().has("tosearch", RegexPredicate.regex("search.*"))
```

**RegexPredicate**

```
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.P;

// https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/heWLwz9xBQc
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/45652897/1497139
public class RegexPredicate implements BiPredicate<Object, Object> {
    Pattern pattern = null;
    private Mode mode;

    enum Mode {
        FIND, MATCH
    }

    public RegexPredicate(String regex, Mode mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    };

    public RegexPredicate(String regex) {
        this(regex,Mode.FIND);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(final Object first, final Object second) {
        String str = first.toString();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        switch (mode) {
        case FIND:
            return matcher.find();
        case MATCH:
            return matcher.matches();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * get a Regular expression predicate
     * 
     * @param regex
     * @return - the predicate
     */
    public static P<Object> regex(Object regex) {
        BiPredicate<Object, Object> b = new RegexPredicate(regex.toString());
        return new P<Object>(b, regex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm way late on this, but I was trying to figure this out as well and hope it helps someone out there. This is implemented in Java. TinkerPop version 3.2.5. I have no idea how to do this without writing some Java.

1) Create an enum that implements BiPredicate. (Note, this predicate allows wildcards and is case insensitive.)

```
public enum StringCompare implements BiPredicate<Object, Object> {
wildcard {
        @Override
        public boolean test(final Object first, final Object second) {

            String str = first.toString();
            String regex = second.toString();

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

            return matcher.matches();
        }
    }
}
```

2) Create your regular expression following the Java rules. I found this link pretty helpful. http://www.developer.com/java/data/using-java-regular-expressions.html

3) Use the has() method, pass it the property key, and create a new P object.

```
String regex = "Mar.*"; //2
GraphTraversal<Vertex,Vertex> gtv = g.V().has("name", new P<>(StringCompare.wildcard, regex)); //3
```